# How to conditionally show element in react JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a UI dynamically using JSON data which renders `input` or `textarea` elements conditionally.

**Sample JSON Data**

```
[
  {
    type: "input",
    val: "input text",
    name: "Input Field",
    editable: false
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    val: "text area text",
    name: "Text area field",
    editable: true
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    val: "text area text",
    name: "Text area field",
    editable: true
  }
];
```

- I have two values for property `type` one is `input` other is `text`, So if `type` property has value "input" then I am creating an `input` element otherwise `textarea` element.
- I too have extra properties. One of them is `editable`, if it is set to true then user can click on edit button which which show `Send` button later on.

**Issues**

- When I am clicking on edit both input field getting editable and both `Edit` is changing to `Send`

I tried using index and matching with index, but that also did not work.

**My code**

```
{data.map((li, index) => (
      <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        {li.type === "input" && (
          <div className="divCont">
            {li.editable && disabled && (
              <span onClick={editComp}>Edit</span>
            )}
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              disabled={disabled}
              defaultValue={li.val}
            />
          </div>
        )}

        {li.type === "text" && (
          <div className="divCont">
            {li.editable && disabled && (
              <span onClick={(e) => editComp(index)}>Edit</span>
            )}
            {disabled === false && ind === index && (
              <span onClick={editComp}>Send</span>
            )}
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              disabled={disabled}
              defaultValue={li.val}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    ))}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-feather-cri0r?file=/src/App.js)

**Edit / Update**

What I am trying to do

- When the object have property `editable:true` it shows the edit button
  just above the input or textarea element.
- Then when I click on edit I want to make sure that particular input or textarea element is enabled so that user can type. `Edit` button should be changed to `Send` button to send data.

Comment: Please update your question to put your runnable [mcve] **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Be sure to remove anything unnecessary to replicating the problem, like Bootstrap.)

Comment: Cannot repro the issue you're mentioning in the post

Comment: Also you literally have a native `<input>` element inside the `li.type === text` branch of code. So of course it will be editable. This question doesn't make sense

Comment: you have in code {disabled === false && ind === index && (
              <span onClick={editComp}>Send</span>
            )}
and when you click Edit, you run setDisabled(false)
so then you see you Send.
what do you think it should see instead?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? An error? Something not rendering correctly? (Side note: You need to put a `key` on elements in array. But that's largely just a warning...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have edit button on each  `div` and when I click on that button I want to make the input field or text area as enabled and change edit to send, but what is happening here is both are getting enabled when I click on edit

Comment: @SamuelHulla I have edit my post please Do check, and you are getting it wrong if `li.type===text` that dose'nt means it will be editable, it is dependent on  `editable` property, as you can see in my `data object`

Comment: @IvanSatsiuk  if you run the `code sandbox` you will see there are two edit and when I click on one edit it is changing to `send` but other one is  not showing, It should be like, when I click on edit that particular input and edit should change to send and editable respectively

But here one is changing others are not showing edit , please chek the edit

Comment: Going thorugh your code in codesandbox, you've set the correct condition for showing the Send button which is ``disabled === false && ind === index``. Since you're using state ``disabled`` for all the input and textarea elements hence they all will share the same value of disabled hence causing this issue. 
To fix it simply add the logic ``disabled={disabled || ind !== index}`` on your textarea and input elements.

Comment: @VarunArya  hey that worked for disabled part but still that edit button issue is there, when click on edit the other edit is going away (not showing)

Comment: Same thing for that too, use ``{li.editable && (disabled || ind !== index) && (
                  <span onClick={(e) => editComp(index)}>Edit</span>
                )}``

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-kare-0oy81?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @VarunArya yup it worked i was not doing it properly

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same flag 'disabled' to control the state of all your components. Therefore, when you click on send you change it to false for every field and that renders them all editable. The easiest fix would be to use a different flag for each field, but that may not scale well if you need it to.

Comment: I think flag should depends on the button I am clicking, according to index

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I understand that you probably new to React and maybe even programming. Learning is good. Here some updated version of your code which does what you wanted, at least the way I have understood. Note though, I have no idea what you trying to build here, but hopefully it will give you some new start:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function EditableArea({ val, ...rest }) {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(rest.value);

  const handleSend = () => {
    // ... send it somewhere maybe?..
    console.log(value);
    setDisabled(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="divCont">
      {disabled ? (
        <span onClick={() => setDisabled(false)}>Edit</span>
      ) : (
        <span onClick={handleSend}>Send</span>
      )}
      <textarea
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        disabled={disabled}
        placeholder={rest.placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        value={value}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
}

function Editable({ ...rest }) {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(rest.value || "");

  const handleSend = () => {
    // ... send it somewhere maybe?..
    console.log(value);
    setDisabled(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="divCont">
      {disabled ? (
        <span onClick={() => setDisabled(false)}>Edit</span>
      ) : (
        <span onClick={handleSend}>Send</span>
      )}
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        disabled={disabled}
        placeholder={rest.placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

let data = [
  {
    type: "input",
    val: "input text",
    name: "Input Field",
    editable: false
  },

  {
    type: "text",
    placeholder: "text area text",
    name: "Text area field",
    editable: true,
    value: ""
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    placeholder: "text area text",
    name: "Text area field",
    editable: true,
    value: ""
  }
];

function redrerInput({ type, editable, ...rest }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "text":
      return <EditableArea {...rest} />;
    case "input":
      return <Editable {...rest} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="row">
        {data.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            {redrerInput(item)}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is [CodeSandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-tree-d9klx?file=/src/App.js)

But I would strongly recommend to read documentation about React first.

Comment: Hey, I got your point, but you missed one thing here, I have types of element, If  `type: "input",` then I want to make input field and if `type: "text",` then I want to make `textarea`, in real code I can have `checkbox` as well as `radio` also, but those are limited so I can conditionally render them, Now in your code you are only making one input field I and simple Div.

How can I conditionally check for `type` and make that element then handle edit send

Comment: Here we go, obviously you need to refactor EditableArea and Editable to remove code duplication there, but I hope you got an idea. Also where you check for render condition you can check for type: `item.editable && item.type == 'input'`